# What is the best way to automatically download schema changes to SQL Server Express databases from SQL Azure?

Tags: synchronization, schema, azure-sql-database, sql-server-express, sql-server-data-tools

I have hundreds of SQL Server Express databases running over the internet for clients and I have a master SQL Azure database. I am trying to sync the master to each SQL Server Express with filter so that each client gets its data only.

SQL Azure sync is good for the job but I need to sync the stored procedures, views and triggers as well because I will be running webapis from each client connected to its local SQL Server database.

What is the best way to sync data as well as schema changes automatically in this scenario. I don't want to go with replication or VPN scenarios.

Comment: Do you run code at the client site or just have a database deployed and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

Do you own licenses for SQL Compare Pro and SQL Data Compare Pro? These have command lines that can be used to automate the scenario you describe. If you own the Redgate Toolbelt, these are included.

SQLdatacompare.exe has an /include switch that should allow you to specify the tables you need. There are [many other options](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SDC10/Switches+used+in+the+command+line) you can specify.

If you need to only sync certain records in a table you can set a WHERE clause, but this can't be done as a command line switch. Instead you'll need to save the comparison project in the SQL Data Compare UI and use this as the input parameter to the command line.

eg sqldatacompare.exe /project:mysavedproject.sdc

SQL Compare is used for synching up the schema (tables, columns, procs, etc). It has [a similar command line](https://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SC12/Switches+used+in+the+command+line).

If you need additional help feel free to contact our support team at support@red-gate.com

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have looked at these tools but I'm worried about the cost implications. If I have thousands of sql express DB,s running and syncing with a central sql azure what sort of license do I need?

Comment: That's a good question. Most of Redgate tools are per-user licensed, so if it's just you, then you'll just need one copy of each. However, I'm no expert at licensing so I'd recommend you email sales@red-gate.com with this enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using SSDT, this isn't *that* hard. I think you are right to treat data "replication" and schema "replication" separately ("replication" is in quotes in both places!).

Assuming you have a `dacpac` built that reflects the desired state of the Express databases, the choices are:

- Come up with a way of *pushing* changes to each "client" after each build. This probably means maintaining a central register of servers to push to somewhere - if you are already doing this for other reasons it shouldn't be too hard to iterate the list and deploy a dacpac to each of them.
- Allow each client to *pull* updates on some suitable trigger - on launch? on a schedule? In this scenario you don't need the central register, just a file location that the clients can all see so that they can download the dacpac and deploy it to themselves.
- Some variation on one of the two options above, but using tools such as Powershell DSC, Puppet, Ansible, etc., either alone or in combination with one another. With that many servers you are well past the point of wanting to worry about pushing schema changes individually.